# Prevent caching from inside of the cache tag

Tags: cache

Does anybody know, if it is possible to prevent caching from within the cached code/content?

Something like:

```
{% cache ... %}
...
{% do notCache %}
...
{% endcache %}
```

Why? Because if there is a content builder inside of the cache tag, certain content elements could simply disable caching that way by calling  `{% do notCache %}`

Answer (score 2):

No you can't, but you might be able to cache each block individually rather than trying to exclude one of them.

Comment: Agreed. Whenever I need to exclude a portion of code from within a cache tag, I tend to cache the component in chunks, appropriately named.

Answer (score 2):

You should give No-Cache a try: https://plugins.craftcms.com/nocache